# Text appears mangled when bkgd char is curses.ACS_CKBOARD

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I'm trying to use a "haze" character - `ACS_CKBOARD` - as a background, with a custom foreground and background color.

This appears to work okay, but when I call `addstr` to show text on top of the background, the text is garbled. It appears to be a selection of "alternate characters" in place of my "Hello, world!", except of course that some few normal letters show through.

Here's a small screen capture:

[image: iTerm2 Screen with background set to CKBOARD, mangled text in front]

I'm assuming that something has jammed up inside curses. Does anyone know how I can get the correct text to display against this background?

Here's some code that produces the behavior:

```
import curses
import locale

def main(scr):
    curses.init_color(2, 650, 407, 160) # brown
    curses.init_color(6, 149, 113, 78)  # tan
    curses.init_pair(1, 2, 6)
    scr.bkgd(curses.ACS_CKBOARD, curses.color_pair(1))
    scr.clear()
    scr.addstr(10, 0, 'Hello, world!', curses.color_pair(0))
    scr.getch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

FWIW: I'm using iTerm2 on a Mac, Python version 3.5.3. If I run the same code in Terminal, I get a similar result with the wrong color:

[image: Mac Terminal screen with background set to CKBOARD, mangle text in front]

**Update:**

After reading Thomas Dickey's answer, I tried to implement what he suggested. I tried setting the `bkgd` followed by both `clear` and `erase` followed by another call to set the `bkgd`. That didn't work- I got the color without the background characters. Looking at the documentation for `bkgd`, it does specify that *"The change is then applied to every character position in that window",* so that's right out!

Then I found [*window.*`bkgdset(char[, attr])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.bkgdset), which *does not* immediately apply it's setting to every character position. Instead, it just applies to newly-drawn bits. With that function, I modified my code as follows:

```
    curses.init_pair(1, 2, 6)
    scr.bkgd(curses.ACS_CKBOARD, curses.color_pair(1))
    scr.erase()
    scr.bkgdset(' ', curses.color_pair(1))
    scr.addstr(10, 0, 'Hello, world!', curses.color_pair(0))
```

And that works! Here's a screenshot to show the result:

[image: iTerm2 screen with background ACS_CKBOARD, with clear text]

Thanks, Thomas, for the suggestion about resetting the background after the paint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **background character** (which you have set with `scr.bkgd`) is a combination of video attribute, color pair and character which is merged with other characters added to the screen, e.g., via `scr.addstr`.

For what it's worth, X/Open Curses documents the feature in  [Rendition of Characters Placed into a Window](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/intov.html#tag_001_004_004).

The alternate character set aspect is one of those video attributes, and as documented by X/Open Curses:

> the attributes specified, OR-ed with the window attributes.

If you don't want that, you can

- temporarily set the background, erase the window (filling the background) and reset the background without the alternate character set, e.g.,

```
    scr.bkgd(curses.ACS_NORMAL, curses.color_pair(1))
```

- use a different method for adding characters to the screen.  The underlying curses library [waddchstr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html) passes the video attributes directly (no merging).  But it does not appear to be part of the Python binding (nothing similar in the [reference manual)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).  The *attr* parameter of [`addstr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.addstr) likely refers to the *window attribute* (set with a similar function (in X/Open curses, the "window colour").

Given the available functions (and limitations of the binding), calls with `scr.bkgd` are the way to solve the problem.